# Xacro Macro Param Not defined

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, parameter, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a xacro file that has some generic macros for inertia. Currently using this for Noetic but I used the exact file on a previous project in Melodic.

The error I get is:

name 'm' is not defined
when evaluating expression 'm*(3*r*r+h*h)/12'

coming from the Marco:

```
 <macro name="cylinder_inertia" params="m r h">
        <inertia  ixx="${m*(3*r*r+h*h)/12}" ixy = "0" ixz = "0"
                    iyy="${m*(3*r*r+h*h)/12}" iyz = "0"
                    izz="${m*r*r/2}" /> 
</macro>
```

Thank you for any assistance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399399/xacro-macro-param-not-defined/) by [jt_axis](https://answers.ros.org/users/102734/jt_axis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-04-23**:\

1. The correct syntax is `<xacro:macro name=`.
2. Have you checked the **calling** tag for `m="1.0"` property? Quotes are required around value.

**Comment by [jt_axis](https://answers.ros.org/users/102734/jt_axis/) on 2022-04-25**:
Yeah, the xacro tag was what was missing, on the macro definition and on the calling of the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So as Mike Scheutzow mentioned the correct syntax is:

```
<xacro:macro name =
```

I was missing the xacro: tag on both the definition of the macro and the calling of it. An example of how it is now, is below:

Definition:

```
<xacro:macro name="box_inertia" params="m x y z">
    <inertia ixx="${m*(y*y+z*z)/12}" ixy = "0" ixz = "0" iyy="${m*(x*x+z*z)/12}" iyz = "0" izz="${m*(x*x+z*z)/12}" /> 
</xacro:macro>
```

Use:

```
<xacro:box_inertia m="${weight}" x="${length}" y="${width}" z="${height}"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [jt_axis](https://answers.ros.org/users/102734/jt_axis/) with karma: 16 on 2022-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0